# Performing buffering/windowing with overlap add CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, core-audio, vdsp

I'm trying to perform some basic DSP functions on PCM audio data which I retrieve from a video file using AVAssetReader on the iPhone.
I'm reading the buffers correctly, number of samples per buffer is 8192 (is that by default? can that be changed?).
However, I need to perform windowing, fft and various other manipulations on slices which aren't 8192 samples long. In fact I want to process 512 samples at a time with 50% overlap between each slice.
I've been digging deep in Apple's Accelerate/vDSP framework and I think I can handle the processing and such, just not sure how to actually split up my signal the way I want it.
I have a strong DSP background but unfortunately my DSP programming experience pretty much ends in MATLAB.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper I found CASpectralProcessor in PublicUtility of the CoreAudio developer tools, which from ver. 4.3 onwards is no longer bundled with XCODE. To download go to
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-

CASpectralProcessor is exactly what I need, a full blown spectral analyzer that includes customizing window length, window type, hop size. Even performs IFFT with overlap/add!

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: As an addition to your answer: I could not find the utility classes in the download section (might be something wrong with my eyes), but I did find them here (press download source code at the top): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Listings/CoreAudio_PublicUtility_CASpectralProcessor_cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can chop 1 or 2 of those large buffers into a number of buffers of some shorter desired length and feed those shorter buffers or slices to your processing routine.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw2, I was guessing that's what I'd end up having to do. Just hoped that maybe there were some internal functions in the vDSP framework to automatically handle all that stuff.